# How to get the HTML code of a RMarkdown Document?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am trying to make a portfolio of R projects on Google Sites, and am currently trying to embed my .html file in the Google Site. I have it published to RPubs, but RPubs doesn't allow me to embed it in GSites. Thus, I think my next best option is to type in the html code for my Rmd file in the embed field in Google Sites. However, I do not know how to get the html code of my RMarkdown file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render the file like you normally would and then once it's rendered either right click on the file and select open with and then open with a text editor. Or open the file in a browser and then right click and choose view source.

That's how to view the html code. I'm not sure if this will solve your overall problem though...
I'm not familiar with Google sites. Is there an option to just upload an html file?